# Deploying application that use Oracle and EF without install ODP.NET Managed Access in production server

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, odp.net

I have developed an application that using EF db first and an Oracle db and it have worked well in the local development environment. At first I don't like the approach to install something to the GAC, in this case is the ODAC that contain ODP.NET Managed Data Access, and chose to use the NuGet version of it in my app. But it failed when I tried to generate the EDMX using EF db first. So I went on and I followed [this instruction](https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/) when developing the app to work with EF database first and an Oracle database.

The problem arise when I had to deploy it into the production and the manager didn't allow to install ODP.NET Managed Data Access in that server. I tried to manually copy the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll into the production environment but still failed.

This is the exception thrown:

> System.ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the
>   machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the
>   inner exception for details.
>
> InnerException: System.ArgumentException Message: Unable to find the
>   requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

This is the app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="theConnectionString" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to deploy it without installing anything in the production server?

Comment: Perhaps you also have to copy file `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll` to production server.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I already did that but it still gave the same exception

Comment: Run [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and check which file is missing.